# Fetching the posts of the profiles the user follows

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, relational-database

In my db schema I have two tables

1. UserPublisher table : It contains info the number of user profiles the currently loggedIn user follows. A single user follows multiple profiles

[image]

2. Post table : It contains posts which the users post.

[image]

Now I want to fetch the posts of the user profiles which the current user follows.

I am using hibernate for object relational mapping.

Presently I am fetching the profiles which the user follows & then running the query on POST table for the list of user profiles.

```
Integer userId=loggedInUser.getUserId();
Query query= sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from UserPublishers u where u.userId=:userId");
query.setParameter("userId", userId);
List<UserPublishers> userPublisherList = query.list();
//Now fetch the posts for users in this list from the POST table
```

What this be the best approach? I do have to fire two db queries in this scenario, I was hoping could this be achieved may be in one single query or some other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about something like

```
SELECT Post.* FROM Post
INNER JOIN UserPublisher ON Post.user_id = UserPublisher.user_publisher_id
WHERE UserPublisher.user_id = {currentSessionId}
```